# How to create an list in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I am creating a form and I would like to create an unordered list of links. My problem is that I don't know how to go about this. I didn't see anything in the forms API about accomplishing this. What is the correct procedure to produce an unordered list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single correct procedure to output HTML - as Ankit mentioned in his answer, one way is to add the raw HTML to the `#markup` property of an element in the form. Nothing wrong with that at all.

You could also use [`theme_item_list()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) which produces a simple HTML list with configurable attributes, and a bunch of default classes so you can target certain elements easily (see the docs for full details).

```
$items = array('First item', 'Second item', '...');
$form['some_element'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $items,
);
```

will output

```
<div class="item-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li class="last">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

it will probably inherit some of Drupal's core or your custom styles because of "item-list" class on the wrapper. That may or may not be what you want, so for this case I guess what you use will likely depend on that styling.

Comment: I selected this as the best answer since it seems more like the "Drupal" way to do it (meaning letting Drupal handle all the markup). Although using markup is just as valid solution, this seems just a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `#markup` of the form api to create the unordered list of links, the documentation of [#markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute) explains it well. Any valid html content can be added to the form using the #markup.